# Functional programming in C#, how can I handle statements like logging, rendering ui, etc?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I read this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach

and the article says:

> The first reason is that doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects. The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect. The call site of this thing would look an awful lot like an expression (though, admittedly, since the method is void-returning, the expression could only be used in a “statement expression” context.) It does not sit well with me to make the one and only sequence operator that is only useful for its side effects.

but I think I should executes statements (void-returning methods) like logging, rendering user UI, write into physical disk, etc...
cannot this job perform with 'functional' way?

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();
var query = list.Where(...).. some 'functional'-feeling combined function chains;
foreach (var log in query)
  Console.WriteLine(log);  // this is the 'right' way?
query.MyForEach(log => Console.WriteLine(log)); // this works, but violates functional programming principles
```

To summarize, How can I handle jobs that causes side effects by functional programming principle?

Comment: `IEnumeratble.Where` is not functional programming, it's setting up a filter on a collection.

Comment: `ForEach` is not a functional approach=) Functional style involves some mental gymnastics (which I'm not smart enough to explain even to myself ) with monads and such to work with side effects.

Comment: You know the nice thing about C#? You can use functional programming when it makes sense, and ignore it when it doesn't. Want to use a foreach loop? No one is going to come beat you over the head because it's "not functional".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Simon Peyton Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Peyton_Jones) once quipped, if all you have is [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), the only observable effect of running them would be a hotter CPU, after which a student responded that a hotter CPU is also an observable side effect.

It's clear to everyone doing functional programming that some impure actions have to happen. You have to be able to repaint the screen, write to disk, send bits over the network, take user input, etc.

Functional programming is not about the elimination of impure actions, but it's an explicit goal to minimise them and control where they take place. A common architecture is [functional core, imperative shell](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell), which is typically [like a sandwich](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/03/02/impureim-sandwich): Gather data from impure sources, pass all the data to pure functions, and do something impure with the result.

In the code sketch given in the OP, you might split it up like this: You'd have a pure function that contains code like this:

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();
var query = list.Where(/*...*/) //.. some 'functional'-feeling combined function chains;
```

Another part of the program - typically the entry point - would call the pure function and decide to do something with it:

```
foreach (var log in query)
  Console.WriteLine(log);
```

In C# you might as well use `foreach` as Eric Lippert suggests, since that's the most idiomatic.

You could also use a `ForEach` extension method. Some people do that, but it makes no difference. Such an action is inherently impure, so it doesn't make it any more or less functional.

I'm not sure I completely agree with Eric Lippert's position, but I acknowledge the argument. Even though, a nice `ForEach` extension method can sometimes save a line of code.

It's not as though actions like that doesn't exist in Haskell, which has [mapM_](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM_) and [forM_](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forM_) for exactly such purposes.

---

Historically, there's been a few failed attempts at figuring out how to best model impure actions in functional programming - particularly in statically typed languages - but for the last few decades, the *general* solution is to model effects with [monads](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/03/28/monads).

Often you can model things in simpler ways by thinking about things differently, but if all else fails, you can always model local state mutation with the [State monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/06/20/the-state-monad).

If you also need to perform [I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) (and you *always* do), Haskell offers the opaque [IO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:IO) monad. You wouldn't use something like `IO` in C#, but it's interesting to [think about what that would look like](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/06/08/the-io-container).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is 'monads'.  The slightly longer answer is a little more nuanced.  As another answer here highlights, in Haskell (a pure functional language), it uses the concept of the IO monad to 'push to the edges' any concept of interacting with the outside world.

You can see this in action in the equivalent of `Main` in Haskell:

```
main :: IO ()
main = ...
```

It forces IO on its `main` function, and so everything produces *something* (and not just heat).

If we take a step back and consider what 'interacting with the world' means.  Let's imagine we had a single value that represented 'the world':

```
public record World(List<Tree> Trees, List<Cloud> Clouds, ...);
```

Then imagine that the passage of time is represented by events affecting the state of the `World`.  So, we'd need a method that took an event and gave us a new `World`:

```
World OnEvent(World world, Event event);
```

We can then take a stream of events and model interaction with the `World`:

```
var newWorld = events.Aggregate(initialWorld, OnEvent);
```

This models causality and changes to a 'global' world.  `OnEvent` would then be a method that would fire off lots of *pure* functions which would transform the old `World` into a new `World`.

Obviously unless you're building a world simulator, this is still just a heat generating exercise.  But it's an interesting way to think about the IO monad.

The IO monad is effectively the manager of *the real world* state.  It is the thing that's allowed to make changes to the real world - except it's not a `World` value, it's the actual world that we live in.

In C# we can build our own IO monad.  So let's give that a go:

```
public delegate A IO<A>();
```

In Haskell, monads are used with `do` notation:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr "What is your name? "
  name <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name)
```

In C# that might look like this:

```
static IO<Unit> MainIO() =>
    from _1   in PutStr("What is your name? ")
    from name in GetLine()
    from _2   in PutStrLn("Hello " + name)
    select default;
```

To make this work with the `IO<A>` delegate that we've created, we need to implement `Select` (aka functor map) and `SelectMany` (aka monadic bind)

```
public static class IO
{
    // Allows us to lift pure values into the IO domain
    public static IO<A> Pure<A>(A value) => 
        () => value;

    // Functor map
    public static IO<B> Select<A, B>(this IO<A> ma, Func<A, B> f) => 
        () => f(ma());

    // Monadic bind
    public static IO<B> SelectMany<A, B>(this IO<A> ma, Func<A, IO<B>> f) => 
        () => f(ma())();

    // Monadic bind + projection
    public static IO<C> SelectMany<A, B, C>(
        this IO<A> ma, 
        Func<A, IO<B>> bind, 
        Func<A, B, C> project) => 
        ma.SelectMany(a => bind(a).Select(b => project(a, b)));    
}
```

Also we need `Unit`, which is a type that has only one value:

```
public struct Unit {}
```

> - `bool` has two values: `true` and `false`
> - `void` has zero values
> - `Unit` is in-between with just one value - itself - it's the functional world's void

We can now make the `PutStr`, `PutStrLn`, and `GetLine` functions:

```
public static class ConsoleIO
{
    public static IO<Unit> PutStr(string value) =>
        () =>
        {
            Console.Write(value);
            return default;
        };

    public static IO<Unit> PutStrLn(string value) =>
        () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            return default;
        };

    public static IO<string> GetLine(string value) =>
        Console.ReadLine;

}
```

So, if we go back to our IO monad main function:

```
static IO<Unit> MainIO() =>
    from _1   in ConsoleIO.PutStr("What is your name? ")
    from name in ConsoleIO.GetLine()
    from _2   in ConsoleIO.PutStrLn("Hello " + name)
    select default;
```

Then we can run it like so:

```
// This doesn't run the IO
IO<Unit> computation = MainIO();

// This does
var result = computation();
```

So, running `MainIO` only produces a data-representation of your program: i.e. it's *pure*.  A program that upon running only creates a data structure (and no other side-effects) *must* be pure.

The invocation of the `computation` runs the IO *for real*.  This is why Haskell is called a pure language.  Because it produces an IO computation which is then invoked by the runtime of Haskell.

This might seem like a sleight of hand, and to a certain extent it is.  It is however true that your code just produces a data structure that is then used to run the real effects.  But it is also true that Haskell and all pure functional languages do change the real world, having real world side-effects.

The critical aspect of this is that we now know that `IO<Unit> MainIO()` has a side-effect.  It's there, writ large, in the prototype of the method.  That's why in your example of `foreach` or `ForEach` is problematic: there's no declaration of any side-effect, it just happens, and we have no idea it happened.  Did some logging happen? No idea.  Were nuclear weapons launched?  No idea.

In Haskell you can't invoke the IO delegate to get the value out (that's done in the runtime), so once you're in an IO context, you can't get out of it.  That means a bit like `async` in C#, once you're in an IO context, it spreads.  This is a good thing, as it forces declarative methods and functions throughout your code-base.  It also makes mixing of different contexts harder - because it should be.  If you're going to drop some IO in the middle of your lovely pure code, then feel the pain of that declaration explosion, and think to yourself: This is the blast radius of how far my single-line-of-code-change has gone.  This is the code that I should consider to be affected/impacted.  It certainly gives you a different perspective on the impact of what seems like minor changes.

> Technically Haskell does allow you to get out of the IO monad using `unsafePerformIO`, but it's considered bad practice.  It is the equivalent of us invoking the `IO<A>` delegate.  We should only invoke it once, in our `Main` method.

So, what about logging?  Or other side-effects.  Well there's other types of monad that supports these things, and the different flavours of monad gives different capabilities.

For example, this is the `Writer` monad - that has an additional capability called `Put` that allows logging of values from within the expression:

```
public delegate (A Value, Seq<string> Output) Writer<A>();

public static class Writer
{
    public static Writer<A> Pure<A>(A value) =>
        () => (value, default);
    
    public static Writer<Unit> Put(string value) =>
        () => (default, Seq1(value));

    public static Writer<B> Select<A, B>(this Writer<A> ma, Func<A, B> f) =>
        () => ma() switch
        {
            var (value, output) => (f(value), output)
        };

    public static Writer<B> SelectMany<A, B>(this Writer<A> ma, Func<A, Writer<B>> f) =>
        () => ma() switch
        {
            var (avalue, output1) => 
                f(avalue)() switch
                {
                    var (bvalue, output2) => (bvalue, output1 + output2)
                }
        };

    public static Writer<C> SelectMany<A, B, C>(
        this Writer<A> ma,
        Func<A, Writer<B>> bind,
        Func<A, B, C> project) =>
        ma.SelectMany(x => bind(x).Select(y => project(x, y)));
}
```

> I'm using `Seq` - an immutable list - from [language-ext - a functional framework for C#](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) (Disclaimer: I'm the author)

We can then do logging in the expression.  There's no need to manually manage the log or anything, just call `Put` with a value and the monad does the rest.

```
var computation = from x in Writer.Pure(100)
                  from y in Writer.Pure(200)
                  from _ in Writer.Put($"The sum is: {x + y}")
                  select default(Unit);
```

We can then run the `computation`

```
var (value, output) = computation();
```

Which gives us the result of the expression (in this case `Unit`) and a `Seq<string>` of logged entries.

Now for the painful bit:

- You can't mix monadic types in LINQ expressions

  - That doesn't mean you can never switch between monads, you can, but just not in the same LINQ expression - unless there's bespoke overrides for `SelectMany`
- Therefore: you need to build a monad that captures all of the kinds of side-effects you expect to run in any one expression (IO, logging, etc.)
- Haskell has a concept of monad-transformers (the ability to combine two monads of different flavours into something more powerful without doing lots of work).  We can't do that in C#, although we can manually write extension methods to work with nested monadic types.

Personally I think it's worth the effort:

- Your code instantly becomes more declarative
- It's possible to bury messy things like state-management, configuration, dependency-injection, logging, IO, optional-values, error-handling, etc. into the monad's bind function (`SelectMany`) and then never worry about it again - it's true abstraction.

  - This also means you can change it easily in the future too

So, hopefully that makes it clear?  We're not trying to never have side-effects, we're trying to *declare* side-effects (like we do with `async`) - and we're trying to make usage of them compositional.  Some people really don't like this approach to engineering, especially in C# where it's not considered idiomatic.  I happen to think it's the single greatest feature of C# (monad support via LINQ) - it's the closest you can get to pure-functional programming in a language that was never originally designed for it.

To do this style of pure functional programming in C# requires a bit of self-control to not *cheat the system*.  Luckily my [language-ext project](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/) has done all of the difficult stuff of building a functional framework that helps the inertia of your code go towards more of the pure functional paradigm, rather than the imperative one.

And [the wiki](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/wiki) has a section on [how to deal with side-effects](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/wiki/How-to-deal-with-side-effects) as well as [how to think functionally](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/wiki/Thinking-Functionally).

And finally, [there are some samples](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/main/Samples/EffectsExamples/Examples) of the `Eff` monad (effect/IO monad), and `Aff` monad (asynchronous effect/IO monad) in action.  They handle: configuration, environment, error-handling, dependency-injection and IO.